# Namespace conflict on bridging header and framework with swift and objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a mixed project that uses both **Objective-C** and **Swift**.

With Cocoapods I import a framework that has a class named `User` inside it. But inside my own project, I  also have an Objective-C class named `User`.

On my Swift file I want to use the Objective-C `User` class but also import the Cocoapod Swift Framework.

My `User` class is imported inside the Bridging Header file, but I'm getting this error:

```
'User' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
```

on this line of code:

```
let user = DTKSession.getShared().user as! User
```

When I searched for this error, I couldn't find anything related to my situation, but I thought it could be something about namespace conflict, since this problem started after I imported the Swift Framework that has the other User class.

I read that if I wanted to specify the Framework class, I could write `FrameWorkName.User`, but I couldn't find how I can specify the class on the bridging header.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try namespacing the `User` class. It would look like this:

```
// use the class from different frameworks
let user1 = Framework1.User()
let user2 = Framework2.User()

// use the class from the main project
let user4 = User()
let user3 = MyProject.User()    // also works like this, if you want to be explicit. Here MyProject is the product module name
```

Try with the fourth option.

Otherwise the easiest way would be renaming your objective-c `User` class.